# The remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized when i try to save my json data

Tags: json, web-services, c#-4.0, http-status-code-401

i want to post the json data to a webservice.

**Here is the method:**

```
      public static Int32 SaveCashSale(string username, string key, CashSale cashSale)
    {
        try
        {

            // Customize URL according to geo location parameters
            var url = string.Format(cashSaleUrl, username, key);

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string jsonData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    activity_date = cashSale.activity_date = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                    added_by = cashSale.added_by,
                    amount_paid = cashSale.amount_paid,
                    balance = cashSale.balance,
                    currency = cashSale.currency,
                    customer = cashSale.customer,
                    grand_total = cashSale.grand_total,
                    modified_by = cashSale.modified_by,
                    price_type = cashSale.price_type,
                    sub_total = cashSale.sub_total,
                    total_quantity = cashSale.total_quantity,
                    workspace = cashSale.workspace,
                });

                streamWriter.Write(jsonData);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
            {
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;

                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data);
                    throw new Exception(sr.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

The system the following error message:
**the remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized.** at this line of the code:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

The url format is:

```
private const string ashSaleItemUrl = "http://avaris.kwekud.com/api/v1/sales/cashsale/?username={0}&api_key={1}";
```

What is wrong with my code and how can i solve it ?

Comment: What does the URL format look like?

Comment: ` private const string ashSaleItemUrl = "http://avaris.kwekud.com/api/v1/sales/cashsale/?username={0}&api_key={1}";`

Comment: Do the username or API key have any characters that would need to be URI escaped?

Comment: no there are just normal username or password, no special characters, ex: username: "abcd", password:"1234"

Comment: @RowlandShaw any idea ??

Comment: If the remote website is something you control, Id suggest debugging that, otherwise, I'd use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) to see if there is any additional information coming in over the wire